# how to update total on click plus and minus button shopify cart page

Tags: shopify

i want to add button plus and minus for qty related when qty clicks then update subtotal without page load.

i am also using the debut theme and the file name is section folder cart-templated.liquid

```
<button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" >-</button>
                    <label for="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-label" data-quantity-label-desktop>{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}</label>
                    <input id="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" type="number"
                      name="updates[]" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
                      data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-quantity-input-desktop data-role="product-quantity-desktop">  
                  <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus">+</button>
```

Comment: You need to check and use Shopify AJAX cart API to update the cart without reloading the page. [Read More](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax/reference/cart)

Answer (score 0):

thanks, but some changes to your code after work. so please check below code.

```
<script>
 function changeQuantity(isIncrease, key) {
 console.log('changeQuantity called');
 const input = document.getElementById(`updates_large_${key}`);
 const currentValue = parseInt(input.value);
 const newValue = isIncrease ? currentValue + 1 : currentValue - 1;

 // Ensure the quantity is at least 0
  if (newValue >= 0) { 
    input.value = newValue; // Update the input's value
    updateCart(key, newValue); // Update the cart
   }
  }

 function updateCart(key, quantity) {
  console.log('updateCart called');
  fetch('/cart/change.js', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  id: key,
  quantity: quantity
  })
})
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(cart => {
    console.log('Cart updated successfully', cart.items_subtotal_price);
    // Here, update the subtotal and any other elements as needed
    // For example, if you have an element for subtotal, you could do 
    document.querySelector('.cart-subtotal__price').textContent = '$' + 
cart.items_subtotal_price / 100.0;
    document.querySelector('.custom-total').textContent = '$' + 
cart.items_subtotal_price / 100.0;

 })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error updating cart:', error));
 }

</script>
```

go to section folder and file cart-templated.liquid in this file find code below and change

```
<span data-cart-item-regular-price>{{ item.original_line_price | money }}</span>

change

<span class="custom-total" data-cart-item-regular-price>{{ item.original_line_price | money }}</span>
```